# sending large packets through websockets

Tags: websocket

I've built a websocket backend with websocketpp, my client will need to download a file thats 1-2 mb on every launch. I can send this in one send request on my server, but is this a good idea? is it ok to do this without chunking it up into smaller data and streaming it if at maximum it will only be 1-2 mbs?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. Web sockets seem to be a thin layer on top of regular sockets so let the TCP/IP layer take care of buffering unless there's a resource reason to break it up. At the receiving end, don't forget that packets can be split or merged when they arrive so, while you can rely on them arriving in the same order, you can't rely on the breaks matching.

If you have a noisy line or failures, you might want to break them up so that you can retry individual blocks rather than try the whole thing but, again, TCP/IP will do its own thing with them.

Caveat: If you are using time-critical apps elsewhere like VOIP, breaking them into smaller chunks will allow the real-time packets to fit into the stream where required but that's an external consideration.